# Input format for BERT fine-tuning on corpus

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I want to fine-tune BERT on a specific language domain using the following git repo:

https://github.com/cedrickchee/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/blob/master/examples/lm_finetuning/README.md

Regarding the input format, it says:

> The scripts in this folder expect a single file as input, consisting
> of untokenized text, with one sentence per line, and one blank line
> between documents. The reason for the sentence splitting is that part
> of BERT's training involves a next sentence objective in which the
> model must predict whether two sequences of text are contiguous text
> from the same document or not, and to avoid making the task too easy,
> the split point between the sequences is always at the end of a
> sentence. The linebreaks in the file are therefore necessary to mark
> the points where the text can be split.

What do they mean with documents in this regard? From my understanding, the `.txt` file used for fine-tuning just contains a lot of domain specific text with one sentence per line. Just to be sure, is it the correct approach to use this repository if I want to fine tune BERT on a specific language domain?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The script you are talking about is the right one for continuing pre-training. The original BERT uses next-sentence prediction as an auxiliary objective. When it is provided a pair of sentences (separated by the `[SEP]` token), the embedding of the `[CLS]` (the very first one) token is used as an input to a classifier telling if the sentences are adjacent in a coherent text or not.

This what the empty lines are for: on a document boundary, the sentences cannot adjacent.

However, the contribution of the next-sentence objective is arguable. For instance, the [RoBERTa](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11692) considers it superfluous and only uses the masked-language-modeling objective a still gets better representation quality than the original BERT.